# MongoDb Replication Issue- when add one more node then primary stops responding

Tags: mongodb, database

I am using mongodb replication

here is the output of **rs.conf()**

```js
firstset:PRIMARY> rs.conf();
{
    "_id" : "firstset",
    "version" : 43,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 7,
            "host" : "primaryip:10002"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 10,
            "host" : "arbiterip:10009",
            "votes" : 2,
            "arbiterOnly" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 12,
            "host" : "secondaryip:10006"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to add another secondary instance. So i just started another mongod process on port 10004 and fired the command

```js
rs.add("secondaryip:10004");
```

I got the output

```js
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

and the state of newly attached instance was

```js
"stateStr" : "STARTUP2",
```

but at the same time my application was not able to connect to primary instance. why ?
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You'll need to give us a bit more info, like the full output of rs.status(). Can you reach each mongo instance via mongo shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug of MongoDB. Bug resolved by MongoDB team from version 2.6.2